# Can you invoke a python routine inside an Android App?

Tags: android, python

There are some cool python scripts out there and I was wondering what is involved in running one within an Android device?  Is this possible? I don't want to call out to a server. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**It is possible, although with limitations.**

The [Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) provides and interface for script languages to expose a great deal of Android's internals.

You will need a specific built of python though, that you can get [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/).

Some libraries are also being simplified and shrunk to be available on Android. For example pyGame (pretty much the standard for 2D games on python) has recently released [this](http://pygame.renpy.org/).

Comment: what I am trying to run needs  antrl python runtime? Do you think this is supported.  I just need to call out to the script from android activity.

Comment: @Androider - I'm afraid I don't have direct experience with it. However the documentation says that "The package is pure Python and does not have any dependencies to non-standard modules.". There are good chances! :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).

Comment: supports atlr python runtime?

Comment: Do you know if an app that uses SL4A needs to install another app in order to run?